# filter data in header based on API key authentication

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, authentication

I want to try to filter data based on API key authentication using NET CORE where the key is stored in the header. each key has its own data.  is there a reference that can help me with that?

for an example like this

[image]

sorry if my question is difficult to understand. thank you very much good luck always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is work demo, you can refer to it.

Using the Custom Attributes, name the Attribute as ApiKeyAttribute.We will be using this attribute to decorate the controller so that any request that is routed to the attributed controller will be redirected to ApiKeyAttribute.

1.ApiKeyAttribute.cs :

```
    public class ApiKeyAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private const string APIKEYNAME = "ApiKey";
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEYNAME, out var extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Api Key was not provided"
                };
                return;
            }

            var appSettings = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEYNAME);

            if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Api Key is not valid"
                };
                return;
            }

            await next();
        }
    }
```

2.Add the API Key inside the appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiKey": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

3. Add `[ApiKey]` to WeatherForecastController

   ```
    [ApiKey]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
   ```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Request.Headers["ApiKey"]` to get value of "ApiKey" header,
using that value do your filter logic

Comment: is there any reference to this? web or youtube link?

Comment: Check This https://www.infoworld.com/article/3617984/how-to-read-request-headers-in-aspnet-core-5-mvc.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).